# При нажатии на ссылку вывести её содержимое

Tags: javascript, dom

Не получается сделать вывод содержимого ссылки в `<input>` формы. Вот мой код:

```
function getElem(){
 var elem=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 var result=document.getElementsByName('result');
  for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
    elem[i].addEventListener('click',(function (){
    result.value=elem[i].innerHTML;
  })());
}


}
getElem();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll( 'a' ); // Выбираем все ссылки на странице
var result = document.getElementById( 'result' ); // input, куда выводим результат
  
for ( var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++ ) { // пробегаемся по всем найденным ссылкам
    elem[i].addEventListener( 'click',(function (e){ // действие при клике
        e.preventDefault(); // Отменяем переход по ссылке
     result.value = this.innerHTML; // вставляем содержимое ссылки в инпут
  }));  
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Ссылка 1</a> <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
<input type="text" id="result" />
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так что вся проблема была в this? А почему elem[i] не подходит?

Comment: @YaroslavTheRock `elem[i]` не имеет отношения к той ссылке, на которую мы нажали. С помощью `elem[i]` мы назначаем обработчик ко всем ссылкам.